# SQL Server 2008 Sort with AA above A

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a set of data that has a priority column. The powers that be decided that they want the following order of priorities:

```
AA
A
B
C
D
E
```

When I try to sort this I get

```
A
AA
B
C
D
E
```

Is there a way I can change this?

Cheers,

Steve

Comment: What if you have BB in the list? where should it come?

Comment: AA was an after thought, we wanted to add a higher level of priority than A and not have to change everything that has already been given a priority. I don't expect there to be a BB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is a static result set you can do:

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable
ORDER BY CASE WHEN yourColumn = 'AA' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, yourColumn
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/39695/1)</kbd>

Comment: 'A' and 'AA' is just a sample.. question is about general ordering!

Comment: This is exactly right, the data given is what we are using, so this solution works.

Comment: @EmanueleGreco. My answer was for a "static result set" and guess it is what OP wanted.

Comment: @FilipeSilva nice to know, looking at the comments I understand you're right. And your answer was accepted!

Answer (score 1):

order by `length of column`

try this :

```
 SELECT Col FROM Table1 
    ORDER BY LEN(Col) desc,Col
```

<kbd>[sql_fiddle_demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ab870/2)</kbd>

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to say both were right but didn't realise I couldn't do that until I tried. I can't mark one as useful until I have enough reputation either.